# Print page borders on a multi page output using wkhtmlltopdf

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I have a requirement where I have a header html, Content HTML , and Footer HTML. in css I have put border as 1px solid black for the body. It prints fine for all pages except last page where the content html ends in middle of the page and the borders are not connected to the footer. Please have a look at screenshot attached. The yellow highlighted border is what I am looking for. Please note that the number of rows in content body are dynamic and can change

I had to remove some rows from the html because of character limitation.
wkhtmltopdf version : 12.6
OS : Windows 10

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
   <head><style type="text/css">
                    body {
                    font-family:Times New Roman;
                    position: relative;
                    padding: 5px;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    
                    height: 350px;
                    }
                            
                    .tableArray1 {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    }
                    
                </style>
                </head>
   <body>
      <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableArray1" style="font-size:12px;">
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3" align="center" border="0px" style="vertical-align:top;border-style: hidden;"><b>DOC TYPE</b></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="left" width="18%" border="0" style="padding:5px;border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;"><img width="100%" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"></img></td>
            <td width="50%" height="40" align="center" valign="top" style="border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;">
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>Header Goes Here<br></br><div width="50%" align="left" style="font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px;vertical-align:bottom;border-right-width:0px"><b>IRN :
                     </b></div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" width="32%" style="border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;"/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="left" width="18%" border="0" style="padding:5px;border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;"><img width="100%" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"></img></td>
            <td width="50%" height="40" align="center" valign="top" style="border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;">
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>Header Goes Here<br></br><div width="50%" align="left" style="font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px;vertical-align:bottom;border-right-width:0px"><b>IRN :
                     </b></div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" width="32%" style="border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;"/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="left" width="18%" border="0" style="padding:5px;border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;"><img width="100%" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,"></img></td>
            <td width="50%" height="40" align="center" valign="top" style="border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;">
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>
               <div>Header Goes Here</div>Header Goes Here<br></br><div width="50%" align="left" style="font-size:11px;padding-left: 6px;vertical-align:bottom;border-right-width:0px"><b>IRN :
                     </b></div>
            </td>
            <td align="right" width="32%" style="border-left-style: hidden;border-right-style: hidden;"/>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
   <head><style type="text/css">
                    body {
                    font-family:Times New Roman;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    }
                    
                    
                    tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
                    td { page-break-inside: avoid; }
                    .tableArray1 {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    }
                    .page_break{
                    page-break-after: always;
                    }
                    
                </style></head>
   <body>
      <table  border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableArray1" style="font-size:11px;">
      <tr height="20">
                     <td width="2%" rowspan="2" align="center"><span style="display:block;">S.</span><span style="display:block;">No.</span></td>
                     <td width="20%" rowspan="2" align="center">Description of Goods</td>
                     <td width="7%" rowspan="2" align="center">HSN Code
                        <div>(GST)</div>
                     </td>
                     <td width="6%" rowspan="2" align="center">Currency</td>
                     <td width="5%" rowspan="2" align="center">QTY</td>
                     <td width="5%" rowspan="2" align="center">UOM</td>
                     <td width="5%" rowspan="2" align="center">Rate<br>(INR)</br></td>
                     <td width="10%" rowspan="2" align="center">Taxable Value (INR)</td>
                     <td width="10%" colspan="2" align="center">CGST</td>
                     <td width="10%" colspan="2" align="center">SGST</td>
                     <td width="10%" colspan="2" align="center">IGST</td>
                     <td width="10%" rowspan="2" align="center">Total</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr height="20">
                     <td width="5%" align="center">Rate</td>
                     <td width="5%" align="center">Amount</td>
                     <td width="5%" align="center">Rate</td>
                     <td width="5%" align="center">Amount</td>
                     <td width="5%" align="center">Rate</td>
                     <td width="5%" align="center">Amount</td>
                  </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">1</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">2</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">3</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">4</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">5</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">6</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">7</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">8</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">9</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">10</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">11</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
         <tr height="25px">
            <td width="2%" align="center" style="font-size:8px;">12</td>
            <td width="20%" align="center">Rice</td>
            <td width="7%" align="center">30049099</td>
            <td width="6%" align="center"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">100.34</td>
            <td width="5%" valign="center" align="center">BAG</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">99.54</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">9978.84</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">0.0</td>
            <td width="5%" align="right"></td>
            <td width="5%" align="right" style="font-size:9px;">1196.0</td>
            <td width="10%" align="right">12896.24</td>
         </tr>
              
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
   <head><style type="text/css">
                    body {
                    font-family:Times New Roman;
                    
                    
                    border: 0px solid black;
                    
                    height: 100px;
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    }
                    #watermark {
                    color: #d0d0d0;
                    font-size: 130px;
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(-40deg);
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 50%;
                    height: 50%;
                    margin: 0;
                    z-index: -1;
                    left: 190px;
                    top: 400px;
                    }
                    
                    tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
                    td { page-break-inside: avoid; }
                    .tableArray1 {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    }
                    .page_break{
                    page-break-after: always;
                    }
                </style></head>
   <body>
      
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableArray1" style="font-size:12px;">
                  <tr>
                     <td width="60%" valign="top" style="padding-left:5px;font-size:12px;">
                                                                    Beneficiary Bank Details
                                                                    
                        <div></div>
                     </td>
                     <td align="center" width="40%"><b>Footer Footer.</b><br></br><br></br><b>Authorised Signatory</b></td>
                  </tr>
                 
               </table>
            
   </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Any luck for this problem? I have the same problem when the content of the page is small than A4 page size

Answer (score 0):

check the third page border for body you written as `0px` try with changing to `1px`

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
   <head><style type="text/css">
                    body {
                    font-family:Times New Roman;
                    
                    
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    
                    height: 100px;
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    }
                    #watermark {
                    color: #d0d0d0;
                    font-size: 130px;
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(-40deg);
                    -moz-transform: rotate(-40deg);
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 50%;
                    height: 50%;
                    margin: 0;
                    z-index: -1;
                    left: 190px;
                    top: 400px;
                    }
                    
                    tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
                    td { page-break-inside: avoid; }
                    .tableArray1 {
                    border: 1px solid black;
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    }
                    .page_break{
                    page-break-after: always;
                    }
                </style></head>
   <body>
      
               <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tableArray1" style="font-size:12px;">
                  <tr>
                     <td width="60%" valign="top" style="padding-left:5px;font-size:12px;">
                                                                    Beneficiary Bank Details
                                                                    
                        <div></div>
                     </td>
                     <td align="center" width="40%"><b>Footer Footer.</b><br></br><br></br><b>Authorised Signatory</b></td>
                  </tr>
                 
               </table>
            
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use ::after and ::before for the body and fix the height of these psuedo elements as much you require, try this attached css for the top HTML file.**

```css
body{font-family:Times New Roman;border:1px solid black;position:relative;}body:before{content:"";position:absolute;top:100%;left:-1px;height:150px;border:1px solid black;}body:after{content:"";position:absolute;top:100%;right:-1px;height:150px;border:1px solid black;}tr{page-break-inside:avoid;}td{page-break-inside:avoid;}.tableArray1{border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;}.page_break{page-break-after:always;}
```